# Junit error: Cannot make a static reference to the non static method

Tags: spring-boot, junit

```
Mockito.when(ApiCallImpl.invokeSubmitApplicationForm(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(AppFormDetails.class))).thenReturn(AppFormSubmissionBOResponse.class.getResource("/appFormSubmission_BO_Resp.json"));
```

When I am trying to mock third party service, I am getting below error.

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non static method invokeSubmitApplicationForm(String, AppFormDetails) from the type ApiCallImpl
```

Answer (score 0):

`invokeSubmitApplicationForm` is an instance method, so it needs to be called on an instance, or, in this case, mock instance:

```
ApiCallImpl api = Mockito.mock(ApiCallImpl.class);
Mockito.when(api.invokeSubmitApplicationForm
                  (Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(AppFormDetails.class))
            ).thenReturn(AppFormSubmissionBOResponse
                          .class
                          .getResource("/appFormSubmission_BO_Resp.json"));
```

Comment: I have tried this. I am getting this error:                                                                   
The method thenReturn(AppFormSubmissionBOResponse) in the type OngoingStubbing<AppFormSubmissionBOResponse> is not applicable for the arguements(URL).

Answer (score 0):

If u are using PowerMockito the use below

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
PowerMockito.doReturn("WhatEverYouWant").when(StaticClass.class, "methodName", Mockito.anyString());
```

If using Mockito then adjust otherwise.

Just don't forget to include the static class in the `@PrepareForTest` section.

**EDIT:**

```
call = Mockito.mock(ApiCallImpl.class);
Mockito.when(ApiCallImpl.invokeSubmitApplicationForm(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
        .thenReturn(AppFormSubmissionBOResponse.class.getResource("/appFormSubmission_BO_Resp.json"));
```

this should suffice.

```
private ApiCallImpl call;
```

should be the declaration.

Comment: But I am not using a static class here. Can you tell me whether I have to change my existing non static class?

Comment: Then just change it to PowerMockito.mock(YourClass.class);